# java.net.ConnectException (on port 9000) while submitting a spark job

Tags: apache-spark

On running this command:

```
~/spark/bin/spark-submit --class [class-name] --master [spark-master-url]:7077 [jar-path]
```

I am getting

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call to ec2-[ip].compute-1.amazonaws.com/[internal-ip]:**9000** failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Using spark version `1.3.0`.

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Are you running on Yarn ?

Comment: @Abdulrahman No, standalone mode.

Comment: Do you read some files from local file system, inside your code? if so, use this prefex, "file://" and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Spark is run in Cluster mode, all input files will be expected to be from HDFS (otherwise how will workers read from master's local files). But in this case, Hadoop wasn't running, so it was giving this exception.

Starting HDFS resolved this.